# Intermittent decryption failures in EVP_DecryptFinal_ex when using AES-128/CBC

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, cryptography, evp-cipher

I am using the EVP library found here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit.html

Here are my two encryption and decryption functions:

I am trying to encrypt a string using AES 128 CBC.

The string is usually of the format `word1 word2 word3`

```
char* encrypt(char *s, char *key) {
        unsigned char iv[16] = {[0 ... 15 ] = 0};
        unsigned char outbuf[1024] = {[0 ... 1023] = 0};
        int outlen1, outlen2;

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
        EVP_EncryptInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
        if (EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen1, s, strlen(s)) == 1) {
                if (EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(&ctx, outbuf + outlen1, &outlen2) == 1) {
                        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
                        return strdup(outbuf);
                }
        }
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
        return NULL;
}

char* decrypt(char *s, char *key) {
        unsigned char iv[16] = {[0 ... 15 ] = 0};
        unsigned char outbuf[1024] = {[0 ... 1023] = 0};
        int outlen1, outlen2;

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
        EVP_DecryptInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
        if (EVP_DecryptUpdate(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen1, s, strlen(s)) == 1) {
                printf("After decrypt update\n");
                if (EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(&ctx, outbuf + outlen1, &outlen2) == 1) {
                        printf("After decrypt final\n");
                        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
                        return strdup(outbuf);
                }
        }
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
        return NULL;
}
```

The problem is the decryption final function works on some strings but not on others.

If the string before it is encrypted is something like `cat dog cow`, the decryption works.

But if it is like `bat dog cow`, the decryption fails in particular at the `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex()` function.

**For some strings, the decryption always fails at the `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex()` function. It does not return 1.**

Any idea what the problem could be? Padding maybe? I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably miss that the encrypted string may contain zero-bytes, so the strlen(s) in DecryptUpdate has a too low value. You have to remember from encrypt how long the encrypted data is and use that value for decrypting.

Comment: Oh wow did not know that the encrypted string can contain zero-bytes. Thanks